# How do I add interactivity to a buttonColumn on Flutter?

Tags: android, android-studio, dart, flutter

So in this flutter tutorial: https://flutter.io/tutorials/interactive/

they showed how to build a layout and add interactivity for one button (the favorite button).

Below, there is a buttonSection that contains three icons that are meant to be buttons. My question is, how do I add interactivity for those icons? I have tried putting in a FlatButton inside the buttonColumn as shown here on the **first child of the Widget buttonSection's Container**(the one with launch() => tel):

```
Column buildButtonColumn(IconData icon, String label) {
  Color color = Colors.black;

  return Column(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(icon, color: color),
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          label,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 12.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            color: color,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}    

Widget buttonSection = Container(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
    children: [
      buildButtonColumn(FlatButton
        (onPressed: launch() => ("tel://09069262647"),),
      buildButtonColumn(Icons.near_me, 'ROUTE'),
      buildButtonColumn(Icons.fastfood, 'MENU'),
    ],
  ),
);
```

However, it's giving me an error message that "The argument 'FlatButton can't be assigned to the parameter type 'IconData'. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need a tap for a any widget, you can wrap it with an inkwell. 
https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GestureDetector` [widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) for adding interactivity to any widgets(like container, column, row, icon, etc).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I just wanted to clarify on GestureDetector. I'm trying to use the button to have the app dial a number through URL Launcher. 

I used:
buildButtonColumn(GestureDetector(onTap: launch() => (tel://) ), Icons.call, 'CALL',

But to no avail. What is the work around to this?

Comment: Code under Launch() function will be : launch() async 
{
const url = "tel:1234567";

if (await canLaunch(url)) 
{
   await launch(url);
}

else{
  throw 'Could not launch $url';
}

}

Comment: Hi anmol. I wrote this and it still doesn't work. First, "await launch(url)" isn't valid as there Flutter says there are "Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found." Also, when I call _launch() in my buttonSection Widget, it says that "The method _launch() isn't defined for class 'MyApp'". Again, thank you for the reply. I really do appreciate it.